# How to sync from Google Drive

Tags: wget, synchronization

I am a student. When our course teacher provides a document or materials our CR (class representative) uploads these files to google drive (although piazza is better for academic material). When I want to download an update of the drive I always have to check the drive status, that is boring and time consuming.

So, I need a tool that automatically downloads the changes to the google drive folder, where I just have to provide the path or url of the link.

I'm not sure if `wget` or `rsync` provide this feature or not.

Answer (score 1):

Try `rclone` or `Insync` or `Grive` for example (although `Insync` is not free), to sync your Google Drive to your Linux. Hopefully these tools will work on your flavour of Linux.

Comment: give me a example(how to use)?

Comment: https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive

Comment: investing a bit of reading into something what you want to use is never a bad idea. there is a nice guide on the `rclone` webpage on how to set it up with google drive, you'll find it at https://rclone.org/drive/